# How to check for the end of animate:flip in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

Does anybody know whether there is a way to check for the end of an `animate:flip` animation in a svelte component?

I don't see any events listed for it, no transition events work for it either.

I need to run a function once the flip animation completes to measure the containing element. Because the elements are animated, running the function before the animation completes leads to wrong size. I want to avoid "hackish" solutions with timeouts, etc. because I would need to run them in some `afterUpdate` which may be fired by other "updates" (not necessarily by adding/removing an element in the each block which is using flip), but it seems like there is no other way. Or is there? Thanks for reading.

Comment: This is currently not possible. [There is an issue discussing implementing it though](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4547).